# Hibernate validator @Size show error in hierarquical list cascade

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator

I am editing author entity, inserting new books for the author and new reviews for books. I added @Size validation in the list of books and reviews. When I merge the author entity, @Size validation works for books, but a error ocurrs in my review's list. Even this list having value, for hibernate it is empty. [This is my code](https://github.com/bernadeteaquino/hibernate-validator-exemple).
Why @Size don't work in the second cascade list?

```
public class Author {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Book {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID")
    private Author author;

    @Size(min = 1, message = "At least one review")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Review {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID")
    private Book book;
}

public class AuthorController {    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void update() {
        Author author = new Author();
        author.setName("Kathy Sierra");

        author = repository.save(author);

        Book book = new Book();
        book.setAuthor(author);
        book.setTitle("Head First Java");
        author.getBooks().add(book);

        Review review = new Review();
        review.setDescription("It's fast, irreverent, fun and engaging!");
        review.setBook(book);

        book.getReviews().add(review);

        repository.save(author);
    }
}
```

The displayed error is:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.example.demo.model.Author] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='At least one review', propertyPath=books, rootBeanClass=class com.example.demo.model.Author, messageTemplate='At least one review'}
]] with root cause

javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.example.demo.model.Author] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='At least one review', propertyPath=books, rootBeanClass=class com.example.demo.model.Author, messageTemplate='At least one review'}
]
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please add a minimal example of the code you have a problem with to the post instead of just linking to it.

Comment: So, what error does occur excactly?